# "This Site Cannot Be Reached" for a Single Website on a Single Computer

Tags: windows-10

a single computer cannot access a website; other computers are able to access the website.

none of the below fixes resolved the issue, is there anything else that could be causing this?

Thank you for any additional information, questions, or suggestions.

## fixes attempted

- clearing the browser cache
- resetting network adapter
- trying a different dns server
- unchecking ipv6
- trying a vpn
- trying a hotspot
- disabling antivirus (symantec)
- added site to the trusted sites list in internet options
- tested other webpage naviagtion successfully
- tested navigation to the problem website from other pc's successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a proprietary website address that had recently moved to another IP address, but because of the way the DNS is handled for this application the host file under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` had to be updated to the correct IP Address to get it working properly.